# How do I use VBA to change the text color of Column G if Column J is a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a VBA module to change the text color of cells in Column G if Column J contains a specific value/string.
Any help would be appreciated!

I tried the below in the hopes it would at least change all of the cells in that range per row, then I could (potentially) run something behind that to make H:J black text, but it only changed the color in J.

```
Dim myCell As Range
For each myCell in Range.("G2:J500")
    If myCell.Value="Necessity-Only" Then
        myCell.Font.Color=RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
Next myCell
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using Conditional formatting instead of VBA?

Comment: You could use `myCell.Offset(0,-3).Font.Color`. That said is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting?

Comment: You only need to loop over column J when using @cybernetic.nomad's `Offset(0, -3)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you! That fixed it. Regarding conditional formatting, this sheet is part of a larger workbook that involves a lot of cutting/pasting. I've tried to use  it in the past but the cut/paste caused issues.

Answer (score 0):

The following would work. This is really easily achievable using Conditional Formatting though..

```
Sub test_this()
    Dim myCell As Range
    ' cycle through each cell in column J
    For Each myCell In Range("J2:J500")
        'if the cell contains the text
        If myCell.Value = "Necessity-Only" Then
            'then colour the text (to 255,255,255 white?) in the cell 3 columns to the left
            myCell.Offset(, -3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! As I mentioned above, the way the workbook is used in practice makes conditional formatting less than optimal.

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Fonts in Matching Rows

[image]

```vb
Sub HighlightMatches()

    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the range dynamically.
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("J2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
    ' or statically:
    'Set rg = ws.Range("J2:J500")
    
    ' Write the values from the range to an array
    ' (assuming there are at least 2 cells).
    Dim Data(): Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim drg As Range, r As Long
    
    ' Loop over the elements of the array
    ' and combine the matching cells into a range.
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If CStr(Data(r, 1)) = "Necessity-Only" Then
            If drg Is Nothing Then
                Set drg = rg.Cells(r)
            Else
                Set drg = Union(drg, rg.Cells(r))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
     
    ' Highlight.
    
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        
        Dim cOffset As Long
        
        ' Single Column
        cOffset = ws.Columns("G").Column - rg.Column '
        drg.Offset(, cOffset).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' White
        
        ' Multiple Adjacent Columns
        cOffset = ws.Columns("H").Column - rg.Column ' H:J - 3 columns
        For r = 0 To 2
            drg.Offset(, cOffset + r).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Black
            ' or default color:
            'drg.Offset(, cOffset + r).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        Next r
        ' or simply:
        'Set drg = Intersect(drg.EntireRow, ws.Columns("H:J"))
        'drg.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Black
    
    End If

End Sub
```